# Текст на иконке в actiobar android

Tags: actionbar, android

Возможно ли на иконку, либо рядом с ней добавить текст в actionbar? То бишь, возможно кастомизировать menuitem?

Answer (score 1):

Укажите параметр `withText` и будет вам счастье!

Код:

```
<item
 android:id="@+id/item3"
 android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
 android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
 android:title="@string/item3">
</item>
```

Код взят из [урока](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/177-urok-107-android-3-actionbar-razmeschenie-elementov.html).

Comment: Спасибо, но title ведь берется только из string? А если текст динамически нужно менять, то как быть?

Comment: @makavelka, у `MenuItem` есть метод `setTitle()`.